# How to get last value for each foreign key in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables - posts and comments. Each post has a lot of comments. I need to retrieve last comments of a user all posts where he has ever replied. Like if he commented to a post multiple times I need only the last comment to that post.
So if he commented to 10 posts 43 times, I need only 10 comments (those that were last to each post).

I tried:

```
Comment::where('user_id', $user_id)
               ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
               ->distinct('post_id')
               ->get();
```

But it returns all his comments.

Comment: What do you mean with "it returns all his comments"? If you have a `distinct('post_id')`, you should get the latest comment per post. Can you provide a sample of db rows and the rows you want to fetch / the rows you're fetching ?

Answer (score 0):

put relation in your 'post' model ('post.php').

`public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments','id_post','id');
}`

`public function last10comment (){
    return $this->comments()->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->take(10)->get();
}`

try in your controller : 
call on each post $post->last10comment()` //return array/collection

Comment: How does this solve the OP's issue? It doesn't make sense to use `take` when you don't know how many posts the user has commented. If the user commented on 50 posts, would you change the `->take` to 50? I don't think this is what the OP is after...

Comment: ok, i fixed it. if OP want to show all last 10comment of the each post from the user, just call "$post->last10comment" on each post. or use .map function

Answer (score 0):

I have made a sample comments table and tried with following DB query it return the desired result.

Here is the code.

```
$data = DB::table('comments as c1')
                ->select('c1.col_2', 'c1.col_2')
                ->leftJoin('comments as c2', function($join) {
                    $join->on('c1.post_id', '=', 'c2.post_id');
                    $join->on('c1.id', '<', 'c2.id');
                })
                ->whereNull('c2.id')
                ->limit(10)
                ->get();
```